# Parse HTML JavaSE

Tags: java, html

Привет!
Мне нужно создать утилиту scraber, которая получает веб-ресурсы по URL-адресу. Затем подсчитать количество предоставленных слов на веб-странице и количество символов(только осмысленных слов без тегов и прочего).

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"UTF-8"));
```

С этим я могу получить весь текст на странице (и теги html), так что я буду делать дальше?
Пытался через HTMLEditorKit, но верно ли это?

Может кто-нибудь помочь мне с этим? Что, что можно почитать или откуда начать. Мне нужно использовать только JavaSE. Нельзя использовать сторонние библиотеки.

Comment: Переведите, пожалуйста, текст на русский, Вы на русскоязычном stackoverflow

Comment: @Ep1demic Спасибо! Извините)

Comment: не стоит извиняться)

Answer (score 1):

```
URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
    String line, htmlString = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        htmlString += line;
    }
// Выбираем текст в теге body 
    htmlString = htmlString.substring(htmlString.indexOf("<body"), htmlString.indexOf("</body"));
// Удаляем скрипты
    String tagStart = "<script";
    String tagEnd = "</script>";
    int start;
    while ((start = htmlString.indexOf(tagStart)) != -1) {
        int end = htmlString.indexOf(tagEnd);
        htmlString = htmlString.substring(0, start) + htmlString.substring(end + tagEnd.length());
    }
// Удаляем все теги
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("\\<[^>]*>", "");
// Удаляем табуляцию
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("\t", " ");
// Оставляем по одному пробелу
    htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll(" +", " ");
    System.out.println(htmlString);
```

htmlString содержит все слова в "body" с удаленными скриптами, тэгами, табуляцией и лишними пробелами.
Количество слов можно получить:

```
System.out.println(htmlString.split(" ").length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если нужен текст именно на странице, я бы сделал следующее:

1. Парсил бы только ту часть страницы, что лежит в теге  (ибо имеено в теле html документа описывается значимый контент.
2. Посмотрел бы спецификацию html, и вынес бы все возможные теги в список исключений (чтобы теги словами не считались).
3. Посчитал бы все остальные символы
   В таком случае, грубый подсчёт у Вас будет.